# Spying on asynchronous functions with jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm using jasmine-node to test my server. I want to fake/bypass some validation related code in my user class. So I would set up a spy like this -

```
var user = {
  email: 'email@email.com',
  password: 'password'
}

spyOn(User, 'validateFields').andReturn(user);
```

However the validateFields function is asynchronous...

```
User.prototype.validateFields = function(user, callback) {

  // validate the user fields

  callback(err, validatedUser);
}
```

So I actually would need something like this which fakes a callback instead of a return -

```
var user = {
  email: 'email@email.com',
  password: 'password'
}

spyOn(User, 'validateFields').andCallback(null, user);
```

Is anything like this possible with Jasmine?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways for this. First you can spy and then get the args for first call of the spy and call thisfunction with your mock data:

```
spyOn(User, 'validateFields')
//run your code
User.validateFields.mostRecentCall.args[1](errorMock, userMock)
```

The other way would be to use sinonJS [stubs](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs).

```
sinon.stub(User, 'validateFields').callsArgWith(1, errorMock, userMock);
```

This will immediately call the callback function with the mocked data.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in a callback function and ask whether this function has been called.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to respond with asynchronous 4 years delay, but I've been just wondering how to solve similar issue and figured out that I can combine jasmine `done` callback and `and.callFake` spy method. Consider the abstract sample below:

```
describe('The delayed callback function', function(){

  it('should be asynchronously called',function(done){
    var mock = jasmine.createSpy('mock');
    mock.and.callFake(function(){
      expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });
    delayed(mock);
  });

});

function delayed(callback){
  setTimeout(function(){
    callback();
  },2000);
}
```